# Switch focus between opened dialogs

Tags: android

is there any way to programmatically switch focus between shown dialogs?
To resume...
I need method dialog.requestFocus(), but there is no some like that...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Well this thing that you want to do it is not user friendly you shouldnt do things like this. The dialogs are modal so you should pop it out prompting the user to do some action chose some decision and so on after that the dialog should vanish :)...

Things like requestFocus() it is stupid to be present in the component like dialog on android, cause when the dialog is visible it is logical that it is focused....

BUT,for your pleasure you can do the flowing:

when you decide that you should change the focus hide the dialog A like dialogA.dismiss() and dialogB.show();, if you decide to back to A than dialogA.show();, dialogB.dismiss();...

this is simple hack but if you code syntactically correct it will work